# Docker secrets and Compose compatibility issue

Tags: docker, certificate, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I'm trying to deploy an IMAP server using Docker Compose and Secrets for certificate management. But as soon as do `docker-compose up -d`, I get:

> WARNING: Service "imap" uses secret "key" with uid, gid, or mode. These
>   fields are not supported by this implementation of the Compose file

This warning is repeated for the cert secret as well.

I have checked already for compatibility between the installed compose version and the required version, everything seems OK.

I'm running on Docker engine version **17.06.0-ce**, and Docker compose version **1.14.0**.

---

And this is my compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

    services:
        imap:
            image: cyrus
            hostname: cyrus
            volumes:
                - my_volume_1
                - my_volume_2
                - my_volume_3
                - my_volume_4
            secrets:
                - source: key
                  target: my.key
                  uid: '0'
                  gid: '109'
                  mode: 0640
                - source: cert
                  target: my.crt
                  uid: '0'
                  gid: '109'
                  mode: 0640

            ports:
                - 110:110
                - 143:143
                - 993:993
                - 995:995
                - 4190:4190
            restart: always
            networks:
                - mail
        logger:
            image: gliderlabs/logspout
            hostname: logspout
            volumes:
                - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            networks:
                - mail
            command: syslog://log-server-ip:514

    networks:
        mail:
            driver: bridge
    secrets:
        key:
            file: ./my.key
        cert:
            file: ./my.crt
```

This actually works, but the generated files inside the container have none of the properties they should have (uid: 0, gid: 109, mode: 0640), so I have to change the ownership and mode of the files manually during the container startup.

Any thought about it?

Comment: Well, that happens because this feature is just a mock implementation, and it's likely to remain like this. Found this out thanks to the [comments](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4994#issuecomment-313200509) on the issue I've opened on the Compose Github repo.

Comment: I took the liberty of getting this comment and adding an answer based on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no proper Docker secrets support on `docker-compose`.

According to a comment by a contributor on a github issue,

> The secrets implementation in docker-compose is a mock implementation using host binds. The actual secrets feature is only available to Swarm services, which can be deployed using docker stack deploy.
>
> Those warnings are valid for any version of docker-compose.

([source](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4994#issuecomment-313200509))